# How to copy table formula down in excel without changing entire column data?

Tags: excel

I have an excel table that has a date column. I have been using this table for a while so and I have been manually entering the date. I wanted to use the `Now()` function so that the date gets auto-populated when i create a new row.

However, when I enter the formula, I get a prompt :

> Overwrite all cells in this column with this formula

I want the formula to be copied down but not up. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You do know that `Now()` will update every time the sheet calculates, right?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can achieve the results you want without using VBA.  Lucky for you, it is exceptionally easy to do with the macro recorder with only one minor copy and paste change inside the VBA editor.

If you are adding a new row to the bottom of a table then use the instructions ..

1) Start the macro recorder

2) use your mouse to select the date column header (the cell at row one in the date column)

3) use the keyboard and press Ctrl + Down Arrow to go to the last row in your table.

4) use the keyboard and press Down Arrow

5) user the keyboard and press Ctrl + ; to enter the current date.  Then press enter.  The table should auto expand down one row.

6) stop the macro recorder

Now the fun part.

Open the macro window on the view tab and edit your macro.  It should have five lines, they should look similar to this (but without row numbers)

1) `Range(`

2) `Selection.End(xlDown)...`

3). `Range("`

4) `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =`  the current date will be here

5) `Range(`

Delete row 3) and row)4  and paste this where they were

`ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Now`

That's all there is to it,  good luck!